# 2 samples without replacement from an original sample

Tags: r

I'm performing a permutation test for statistics in R. I have a sample for example  of 6 entries `c<-(40,67,35,67,100,100)`  I want to choose 2 samples one of size `m` from the original sample without replacement which easily can be `sample(c, m, replace = FALSE)` but I need to save the remaining `6-m` elements into another vector. How can I do? Keep in mind that the original sample can have multiple equal entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample in the first run the index and not the value.

```
x <- c(40,67,35,67,100,100)
m <- 2
set.seed(42)
i <- sample(seq_along(x), m, replace = FALSE)
x[i]
#[1]  40 100

sample(x[-i], m, replace = FALSE)
#[1]  67 100
```